# Why is 'is_multisite' returning true when it's a single install?

Tags: multisite

I've installed a single site WP. In one of my plugins, I have  the following code:

```
if(is_multisite) {
  $upload_dir = get_upload_dir();
  $_SESSION['root_image_dir'] =  str_replace('\\','/',$upload_dir['basedir']);
  echo 'IS MULTI.'; //<-- this is outputted every time
} else {
  $_SESSION['root_image_dir'] = '';
  echo 'IS NOT MULTI'.$_SESSION['root_image_dir'];
}
```

For some reason, the `echo` statement is triggered every time.

Why is [`is_multisite`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_multisite) not working?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that's the code you have in your plugin, you're writing it wrong.  You have `if(is_multisite)` which is treating the string `is_multisite` as a constant and evalutation to true.  Essentially you're writing `if(true) ...`

Remember, `is_multisite()` is a *function*.  You need the parenthesis at the end for PHP to actually evaluate the function.  Change your code to the following:

```
if( is_multisite() ) {
    $upload_dir = get_upload_dir();
    $_SESSION['root_image_dir'] =  str_replace('\\','/',$upload_dir['basedir']);
    echo 'IS MULTI.'; //<-- this is outputted every time
} else {
    $_SESSION['root_image_dir'] = '';
    echo 'IS NOT MULTI'.$_SESSION['root_image_dir'];
}
```